# Game Maker Studio 2 Array taking wrong values

Tags: game-engine, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Hey guys I'm new to Game Maker Studio and new to the language. I'm making a game and have been working on the dialogue system.

This chunk of code was designed for characters respond to a set of choices, the dialogue starts by printing out the first element of the `line_array`, which it does, then give the player the choice of two responses from the `response_array`, which it insteads prints out the second element of the `line_array` and I don't understand why.

Does an argument only hold one element of an array? I'm initializing two arrays in an object `oCivilian2` and pushing them through code `DialogueCode` which is linked to another object `oRespond` that supposed to allow me to sift through dialogue in game. Anything helps thanks

It's initialized here in create of `oCivilian2`

```
line_array = [3];
line_array[0] = "Ethan it's good to see you! \n I thought after the incident well.... \n well I thought we had lost you";
line_array[1] = "I've said too much";
line_array[2] = "You hit your head trying to saver her\n It was horrible";
response_array = [2];
response_array[0] = "What happened?";
response_array[1] = "I don't recall alot. How bad was it?";
counter = 0;
x1 = RESOLUTION_W / 2;
y1 = RESOLUTION_H -70;
x2 = RESOLUTION_W/2;
y2 = RESOLUTION_H;
_print = "";
responseSelected = 0;
```

Then the step which links it to `DialogueCode` when spacebar is pressed

```
keyActivate = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space);
if (keyActivate) 
{
    var inst = collision_rectangle(oPlayer.x+3,oPlayer.y+3,oPlayer.x-3,oPlayer.y-3, oCivilian2, false, false);
    if (inst != noone) 
    {
        ScriptExecuteArray(DialogueCode, line_array);
        ScriptExecuteArray(DialogueCode, response_array);
    }
}
```

Then through to step in the object `oRespond`

```
lerpProgress += (1 - lerpProgress) / 50;
textProgress += global.textSpeed;

x1 = lerp(x1, x1Target,lerpProgress);
x2 = lerp(x2, x2Target,lerpProgress);


keyUp = (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up)) || (keyboard_check_pressed(ord("W")))
keyDown = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_down) || keyboard_check_pressed(ord("S"));
responseSelected += (keyDown - keyUp);
var _max = 2;
var _min = 0;
if (responseSelected > _max) responseSelected = _min;
if (responseSelected < _min) responseSelected = _max;

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    var _marker = string_pos(",", response);
    if (string_pos(",",response)) 
    {
        responseScript[i] = string_copy(response,0,_marker);
        string_delete(response,0,_marker);
        var _marker = string_pos(",", response);
    }
    else 
    {
        responseScript[i] = string_copy(response,0, string_length(response));
    }
}
if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space))
{
    counter++;
}
```

Then to print in `oRespond`

```
/// text
//response 
NineSliceBoxStretched(sTextBox, x1,y1,x2,y2, 0);
draw_set_font(fText);
draw_set_halign(fa_center);
draw_set_valign(fa_top);
draw_set_color(c_black);
if (counter % 2 == 0) 
{
    var _i = 0;
    var _print = string_copy(text,1,textProgress);
    
    draw_text((x1+x2) / 2, y1 + 8, _print);
    draw_set_color(c_white);
    draw_text((x1+x2) / 2, y1 + 7, _print);
    _i++;
}
else 
{
    if (array_length_1d(responseScript) > 0) 
    {
        var _print = "";
        for (var t = 0; t < array_length_1d(responseScript); t++)
        {
            _print += "\n";
            if (t == responseSelected) _print += "--> "
            _print += responseScript[t];
            show_debug_message(responseScript[t]);
            if (t == responseSelected) _print += " <-- "
        }
        draw_text((x1+x2) / 2, y1 + 8, _print);
        draw_set_color(c_white);
        draw_text((x1+x2) / 2, y1 + 7, _print);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `_i` variable in `oRespond` don't seem to do much. Havn't you forgotten something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i think to see many problems with your code.

First of all, since arrays in GM are dynamic declare them like

`line_array[3]`

is a bad practice (in my point of view)

I've never declared an array this way in GM so that could be the problem here.

Second, i don't really understand the logic of your code, always create objects, at least in the GM environment, that corresponds to "physical" entities, i would make an object for the Civilian but not for the "respond".

I've red your code a lot of times and since no one answered you in 3 months i can assume it's because no one can really understand your way of coding, and this way of coding will probably give you a lot of problems in future. The thing that you're trying to doing could be super-easy if done with a good hierarchy.

I would like to help u with this code, but i find it very chaotic.

If you've not resolved this problems, write a comment :)

I advice you to fully re-implement it even if resolved anyway.